# Click on TextBlock inside ListView won't let me select the whole ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I got the following XAML-Code:

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" Height="447" Background="#FFC8F0F1" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListViewItem>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}" Foreground="{Binding textcolor}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding foo}" Foreground="{Binding textcolor}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding bar}" Foreground="{Binding textcolor}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ListViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I am starting my program and the code is filling the ListView with ListViewItems, so far so good...

Once I click on the text (Textblocks a.k.a. all the stuff within StackPanel) it won't select/mark the ListViewItem (background-area).

If I click on a free spot where there is no text it's working fine.

I even tried to change ListView to ListBox, it didn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataTemplate` should not contain a `ListViewItem` instance, the control creates those containers for you. If you need to set properties on the container use the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to bind the `ListView's` `ItemsSource` to an ObservableCollection of `FooBar` objects, then it would be trivial:

**FooBarsView**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ListViewSelectingItem.View.FooBarsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewSelectingItem.View"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ListViewSelectingItem.ViewModel"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:FooBarsViewModel x:Key="fooBarsList"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource fooBarsList}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FooBars}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FooBar}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bar}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**FooBarsViewModel**:

```
namespace ListViewSelectingItem.ViewModel
{
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Model;
public class FooBarsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public FooBarsViewModel()
    {
        FooBars = new ObservableCollection<FooBar>();
        FooBars.Add(new FooBar { Foo = "Foo 1", Bar = "Bar 1" });
        FooBars.Add(new FooBar { Foo = "Foo 2", Bar = "Bar 2" });
        FooBars.Add(new FooBar { Foo = "Foo 3", Bar = "Bar 3" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FooBar> FooBars { get; private set; }
}
}
```